# Generating a graph from a rectangular grid for graph searching

Tags: c#, graph

I recently reviewed some code implementing some heuristics which has piqued my interest in the A* graph searching algorithm. I'm going to do that in a bit but first I need a way to create a graph in order to work on...

I could have used `Point` from `System.Drawing`, but I didn't want to include the whole assembly for the single struct. That's potentially a bad reason but here's my reinvented `Coordinate` structure anyway:

```
[DebuggerDisplay("({X}, {Y})")]
internal struct Coordinate : IEquatable<Coordinate>
{
    internal int X { get; }

    internal int Y { get; }

    public Coordinate(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public static Coordinate operator +(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
    {
        return new Coordinate(a.X + b.X, a.Y + b.Y);
    }

    public static Coordinate operator -(Coordinate a, Coordinate b)
    {
        return new Coordinate(a.X - b.X, a.Y - b.Y);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Coordinate)
        {
            return Equals((Coordinate)obj);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * X.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * Y.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public bool Equals(Coordinate other)
    {
        return other.X == X && other.Y == Y;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"({X}, {Y})";
    }
}
```

I decided I would treat each point as a 'tile' and have the cost on that tile rather than weighting the edges directly. I chose `null` as the value representing an impassible tile... I'm not sure I like that now so thoughts welcome.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Location: {Location}, Cost: {Cost}")]
internal sealed class MapTile : IEquatable<MapTile>
{
    internal MapTile(Coordinate location, int? cost = null)
    {
        Location = location;
        Cost = cost;
    }

    internal Coordinate Location { get; }

    internal int? Cost { get; }

    public bool Equals(MapTile other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return Location.Equals(other.Location) && Cost == other.Cost;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as MapTile);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * Location.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * Cost.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Location: {Location}, Cost: {Cost}";
    }
}
```

The underlying data structure for the map is really straightforward:

```
internal sealed class Graph<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> AllNodes { get; }

    private IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> Edges;

    internal Graph(IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>> edges)
    {
        if (edges == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(edges));
        }
        Edges = new ReadOnlyDictionary<T, IEnumerable<T>>(edges);
        AllNodes = Edges.Keys;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<T> Neighbours(T node)
    {
        return Edges[node];
    }
}
```

In order to create a simple 2D rectangular map, I created this map generator class:

```
internal class RectangularMapGenerator
{
    private int height;
    private int width;

    private HashSet<Coordinate> walls = new HashSet<Coordinate>();
    private HashSet<Coordinate> water = new HashSet<Coordinate>();

    private static readonly Coordinate[] CardinalDirections = new[]
    {
        new Coordinate(0, 1),
        new Coordinate(1, 0),
        new Coordinate(0, -1),
        new Coordinate(-1, 0)
    };

    public RectangularMapGenerator(int width, int height)
    {
        if (height < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(height));
        }
        if (width < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(width));
        }
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
    }

    internal RectangularMapGenerator AddWall(Coordinate location)
    {
        if (!IsWithinGrid(location))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Wall location must be within the grid", nameof(location));
        }
        walls.Add(location);
        return this;
    }

    internal RectangularMapGenerator AddWater(Coordinate location)
    {
        if (!IsWithinGrid(location))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Water location must be within the grid", nameof(location));
        }
        water.Add(location);
        return this;
    }

    private bool IsWithinGrid(Coordinate c)
    {
        return c.X >= 0 && c.X < width && c.Y >= 0 && c.Y < height;
    }

    private IEnumerable<MapTile> CreateEdges(MapTile tile)
    {
        if (walls.Contains(tile.Location))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<MapTile>();
        }

        return (from d in CardinalDirections
               let newLocation = tile.Location + d
               where IsWithinGrid(newLocation) && !walls.Contains(newLocation)
               select CreatMapTile(newLocation))
               .ToArray();
    }

    private MapTile CreatMapTile(Coordinate location)
    {
        int? cost = null;
        if (!walls.Contains(location))
        {
            cost = water.Contains(location) ? 5 : 1;
        }
        return new MapTile(location, cost);
    }

    internal Graph<MapTile> Build()
    {
        var edges = new Dictionary<MapTile, IEnumerable<MapTile>>();

        for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                var location = new Coordinate(x, y);
                var tile = CreatMapTile(location);
                edges[tile] = CreateEdges(tile);
            }
        }
        return new Graph<MapTile>(edges);
    }
}
```

An example of actually creating a map is (I only wrote this for CR so not really wanting it to be reviewed):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var mapBuilder = new RectangularMapGenerator(10, 10);

    for (var x = 1; x < 4; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 7; y < 9; y++)
        {
            mapBuilder.AddWall(new Coordinate(x, y));
        }
    }
    for (var x = 4; x < 7; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            mapBuilder.AddWater(new Coordinate(x, y));
        }
    }
    var graph = mapBuilder.Build();

    foreach (var row in graph.AllNodes.GroupBy(n => n.Location.Y))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            string.Join(" ", 
                row.OrderByDescending(a => a.Location.X)
                .Select(a => a.Cost.HasValue ? a.Cost.Value.ToString() : "-")));
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Running the above outputs a map of "costs" that looks like this (which is obviously a river with a boat house next to it ;) ). I've used the convention of origin in the top left with `y` increasing down and `x` increasing to the right like it does in the html canvas. (Edit: No it doesn't! Should have used `OrderBy` for the x axis, not `OrderByDescending`... Result is that the origin is actually in the top right and x increases to the left.)

[image: Results of map generator]

I haven't done this sort of thing before (and I have a Physics background so no CS classes to fall back on) so I'm looking for comments on all aspects of the code. Is putting the `cost` on a tile a reasonable trade off for simplicity, or should I introduce a more modelled edge with the cost on that instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of comments:

- This code looks really nice!

**Coordinate**

- `[DebuggerDisplay]` is redundant when you override `ToString()`.
- I don't mind readonly fields for X and Y there. This is a slight performance optimization. [Further reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-11-ten-questions-on-value-based-programming)
- I usually throw in equality operators when overriding equality:

  ```
   public static bool operator ==(Coordinate left, Coordinate right)
   {
       return left.Equals(right);
   }

   public static bool operator !=(Coordinate left, Coordinate right)
   {
       return !left.Equals(right);
   }
  ```

**About GetHashCode**

- This algorithm will generate collisions for `new Coordinate(1, 2) == new Coordinate(2, 1)`. May or may not be an issue.
- No need to call `X.GetHashCode()` as it returns the value.
- Here is an alternative implementation:

  ```
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       unchecked
       {
           return (X*397) ^ Y;
       }
   }
  ```

**Graph**

- I prefer writing `AllNodes` like this:

  ```
   public IEnumerable<T> AllNodes
   {
       get { return Edges.Keys; }
   }
  ```

  Or if you are using C#6 `public IEnumerable<T> AllNodes => Edges.Keys;`
- I prefer `IReadOnlyList<T>` in all places, it closes the door to accidentally having something lazy that executes on every call. For max performance you want to pass the raw array T[].
- Depending on how it is used `KeyValuePair<T, IReadOnlyList<T>>[]` can have better performance than `Dictionary<T, IReadOnlyList<T>` due to dictionary being a pretty expensive allocation. If there are many elements and you do many lookups per dictionary they are probably right.

Ending here, really nice code, not much of a review.

As with all things related to performance, profile first and profile after if you decide to optimize.

Comment: Thanks - your comments about `GetHashcode` are very helpful as in a rectangular grid (a, b) and (b, a) are very likely to occur so definitely want to avoid collisions there.

Comment: I should probably have split up the microoptimization stuff from the review.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that while your code is clear and well written, if your actual goal is to experiment with A*, you don't need to be so literal with using a directed graph. A simple two-dimensional array of weights is perfectly usable for A*.  In fact this is exactly what many interactive javascript demos of A* do.  It looks as though your final graph is this way too.

If in the future you want to experiment with a sparse graph or a non-rectangular grid (like a hex map or something), with a little work your code is a good starting spot for that.