# Using the A* algorithm to search a graph generated from a grid

Tags: c#, graph, a-star

Following on from my [previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/121368/generating-a-graph-from-a-rectangular-grid-for-graph-searching), I finally got round to actually doing the A* search for the `Graph<MapTile>`. The changes to the code from the previous question were pretty minor (and no API change) so I won't include the code again.

First, I defined an interface for a hueristic.

```
internal interface ICartesianHeuristic
{
    int Calculate(Coordinate start, Coordinate end);
}
```

I then decided to use Manhattan distance because I'm only allowing up, down, right and left (i.e. no diagonal) which seemed pretty standard:

```
internal sealed class ManhattanDistanceHueristic : ICartesianHeuristic
{
    public int Calculate(Coordinate start, Coordinate end)
    {
        return Math.Abs(start.X - end.X) + Math.Abs(start.Y - end.Y);
    }
}
```

I needed a priority queue so I used the first one that came up in Nuget for that search (OptimizedPriorityQueue) which provides the `SimplePriorityQueue` class that I use in the implementation:

```
internal sealed class AStarMapTileSearch
{
    private ICartesianHeuristic hueristic;

    internal AStarMapTileSearch(ICartesianHeuristic hueristic)
    {
        if (hueristic == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hueristic));
        }

        this.hueristic = hueristic;
    }

    internal IEnumerable<MapTile> GetShortestPath(Graph<MapTile> graph, Coordinate start, Coordinate goal)
    {
        var startingTile = GetStartTile(graph, start);
        var frontier = new SimplePriorityQueue<MapTile>();
        frontier.Enqueue(startingTile, 0);

        MapTile foundGoal;
        var paths = GetPathsToGoal(graph, goal, startingTile, frontier, out foundGoal);

        if (foundGoal == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"No path between { start } and { goal } was found.");
        }

        return BuildPathFromPaths(start, foundGoal, paths);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MapTile> BuildPathFromPaths(Coordinate start, MapTile foundGoal, Dictionary<MapTile, Tuple<MapTile, int>> paths)
    {
        var path = new Stack<MapTile>();
        path.Push(foundGoal);
        var current = foundGoal;
        while (current.Location != start)
        {
            current = paths[current].Item1;
            path.Push(current);
        }
        return path;
    }

    private Dictionary<MapTile, Tuple<MapTile, int>> GetPathsToGoal(Graph<MapTile> graph, Coordinate goalLocation, MapTile startingTile, SimplePriorityQueue<MapTile> boundaryTiles, out MapTile foundGoal)
    {
        var paths = new Dictionary<MapTile, Tuple<MapTile, int>>();
        paths[startingTile] = Tuple.Create<MapTile, int>(null, 0);
        foundGoal = null;
        while (boundaryTiles.Any())
        {
            var currentTile = boundaryTiles.Dequeue();

            if (currentTile.Location == goalLocation)
            {
                foundGoal = currentTile;
                break;
            }

            foreach (var neighbour in graph.Neighbours(currentTile))
            {
                int newCost = CalculateCostToMoveTo(paths, currentTile);
                if (!paths.ContainsKey(neighbour) || newCost < paths[neighbour].Item2)
                {
                    paths[neighbour] = Tuple.Create(currentTile, newCost);
                    boundaryTiles.Enqueue(neighbour, newCost + hueristic.Calculate(currentTile.Location, goalLocation));
                }
            }
        }
        return paths;
    }

    private static int CalculateCostToMoveTo(Dictionary<MapTile, Tuple<MapTile, int>> paths, MapTile currentTile)
    {
        return paths[currentTile].Item2 + currentTile.Cost.GetValueOrDefault();
    }


    private static MapTile GetStartTile(Graph<MapTile> graph, Coordinate start)
    {
        var node = graph.AllNodes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Location == start);
        if (node == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"{start} is not within the given graph");
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

I ended up having to implement the search specifically for a graph of `MapTile`s rather than working against any graph because I wanted to use a square grid for verification. Introducing some interfaces like `ICostedNode` and `ICostedGraph` would let me extend it to any graph with costs/weightings but I didn't really want to :)

Here's an example of it working (not really wanting a review of this bit!):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mapBuilder = new RectangularMapGenerator(10, 10);

        for (var x = 1; x < 2; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 9; y++)
            {
                mapBuilder.AddWall(new Coordinate(x, y));
            }
        }
        for (var x = 2; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 8; y < 10; y++)
            {
                mapBuilder.AddWater(new Coordinate(x, y));
            }
        }
        mapBuilder.AddWater(new Coordinate(4, 9));
        var graph = mapBuilder.Build();

        foreach (var row in graph.AllNodes.GroupBy(n => n.Location.Y))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(
                string.Join(" ",
                    row.OrderBy(a => a.Location.X)
                     .Select(a => a.Cost.HasValue ? a.Cost.Value.ToString() : "-")));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Shortest path:" );
        var path = new AStarMapTileSearch(new ManhattanDistanceHueristic()).GetShortestPath(graph, new Coordinate(0,0), new Coordinate(8, 7));
        var pathAsString = string.Join(" -> ", path.Select(p => p.Location));
        Console.WriteLine(pathAsString);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

[image: Graph search result]

I basically followed this blog: http://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html (which is awesome and really well explained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the implementation of A* is concerned, this looks fine and nicely readable.

#### `GetStartTile`

This method reveals a few issues.

Why is it called `GetStartTile`? The `Coordinate` parameter could just as well be any coordinate, I don't see a reason to qualify it as the "start".

With the method and other elements renamed, this seems more natural:

```
private static MapTile GetTile(Graph<MapTile> graph, Coordinate location)
{
    var node = graph.AllNodes.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Location == location);
    if (node == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"{location} is not within the given graph");
    }
    return node;
}
```

However, another strange thing here is the lookup method. Given coordinates, I would think that a location can be accessed instantly (indexed by the coordinates), so the linear search seems not natural.

Lastly, I don't know much C#, but it seems to me that instead of `InvalidOperationException`, `ArgumentException` would be more appropriate here.

#### `GetShortestPath`

This method is almost fine, except it has two responsibilities:

1. Find the shortest path (the main intention)
2. Validate that the start location is valid

This second responsibility doesn't fit well in the method.
In fact it seems strange that it's there at all.

It would be better if this function took `MapTile` parameters that have been already validated. Possibly by a wrapper function taking `Coordinate` parameters.

Also note that in the current implementation goal is not validated at all. Which could be important, because if the goal is not even in the graph, then the program needlessly applies the algorithm until the entire graph is explored.

In general, it's not great when exceptions can be thrown at multiple points in a program. So moving the validation of start and goal out of the graph traversal will be an improvement.

Finally, `InvalidOperationException` doesn't seem an appropriate outcome in case the goal cannot be reached. If the goal doesn't exist in the graph, it would be better to raise that error sooner, as I explained above. If the goal exists in the graph but not reachable somehow, then a custom exception would be better, something like `UnreachableTargetException`.